# Pivot Table Most Current Data Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a work pivot table setup to measure skills of employees. Now the process as it currently stands, is that every few months an employee will go and update one to three of skills.

The pivot table then looks like this:

```
Skills            6/1/2016  12/31/2016  4/3/2017    9/1/2016    Grand Total
Action Oriented         3       4       3           2               4
```

So currently the Grand Total function, takes the max. I was wondering if there is anyway to set up a calculated field in the pivot table, that will take values as of the last date. And if certain skills arn't updated it will just take the the last value thats already in there. 
I.e. if skills: action oriented, creative, and management abilities all got updated on 9/1/2016. But the last time client focus was updated was in June, then this calculation field will take the june value for client focus.

Comment: Why is 9/1/216 the last one when 4/3/2017 comes after?

Comment: Also, what does the pivot table's source data look like?

Comment: Hey Alexis, its just a typo. Pivot Source is vertical: so Name of person, skill ,rating, date.

Comment: This question is quite a bit harder than I initially suspected, but I have a work around that uses Power Query if you're interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is stored in the Excel data model (Power Pivot) you can use DAX-functions to check for the latest date values only. This provides a lot more feature than the regular pivot table and is quite easy to set up (just click "import from table" if you data is already stored in Excel).

I don't know what the source table looks like but you can either create a calculated column to check for the MAX([date] / LASTDATE[date] or create a measure / calculated field to count or sum up values with the last date only as in `=CALCULATE(SUM([you value column]),LASTDATE([your date column])`.

Check [this](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiow4iTz5nOAhWDwBQKHXT3DI0QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fee634380.aspx&usg=AFQjCNFl7xZBfr4BBu373wYyYT2u9RbPNw&sig2=ZKgBmVZsbfpo29_N2YFxRw&bvm=bv.128617741,d.bGg) for more info.

Comment: I tried something like this, but couldn't figure out how to add a single aggregate column without adding columns for each date too (e.g. [this](https://i.imgur.com/SjWJurj.png)). How do you get just the Total Measure column and each of the individual Rating columns?

Comment: Don't add the column in the pivot table.. the pivot table is only for displaying values. Whenever you change the fields in the pivot table, the manual calculations get screwed up.

Import your data into the Excel Data Model. Go to options, add-ins, com-add-ins, activate PowerPivot. Then you can access the model (menu, green icon) and create a column right there. Once created, create a new pivot table from this menu and you now have access to the new column/measures.